# How to add pins to Apple map when I use URL to call apple map app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-maps

I want to call apple map app via url link and put pin(s) at specific location(lon/lat) in the app. I have tried some methods in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html
,but it does not work.

Is it possible? I have no idea now, really need some help.

Would you please give me some advice?

Comment: That is something you can do in your own app, with more control too.

Comment: I just want to call apple native map app,  I did not use mapKit for development. Do you have some ideas?